# why is this program taking integer and alpha numeric inputs and printing them? does std::string in c++ take integer values as well?

Tags: c++, string

The output of this code is 'gh9-87' when the input is given as 'gh9-87'. Why does it take alpha-numeric value? Does std::string take alpha-numeric value as input?

```
 #include <iostream>

 int main() {

 std::string var;

 std::cout << "Enter an input: " << std::endl;
 std::cin >> var; //user input
 std::cout << "The value of var is: " << var;

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what else it would do. Can you share what you expected? It's not clear what you are asking exactly.

Comment: Why do you expect it to *not* take alphanumeric inputs? `1` is a character, as much as `a` is.

Comment: I don't think this question is any big mystery, guys

Answer (score 1):

Extracting bytes from a stream into a `std::string` doesn't discriminate. It just takes bytes. These bytes, if they're ASCII or UTF-8 encoded or something else, can look like alphabet characters or numeric digits or symbols or whatever they are.

If you expected `std::string` to only accept A-Z from a stream, that expectation was incorrect.